# Mat stepper does not shows connecting lines when used in for loop

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using mat stepper which is bind with mat expansion panel, both are generated in ngFor loop according to the size of array. but the problem is that the stepper does not shows the connecting lines the it only acts as a bullet-ed list.

```
<div *ngFor="let currentUserInteraction of currentUserInteractions">

  <mat-vertical-stepper #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="currentUserInteraction">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>{{currentUserInteraction.name}}</ng- 
             template>
      <mat-expansion-panel>
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
     </mat-expansion-panel>
        </mat-step>
     </mat-vertical-stepper>

   </div>
```

and also , how to display label on both sides of vertical stepper.

Comment: How did you import the module?

Comment: import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';

Comment: @RazaEllahi can you share your stepper code on https://stackblitz.com?

Comment: I am new in angular, can you create stackbliz with this example using ngFor loop to generate stepper

Comment: You are creating several steppers! You just need to create a step for each of your current user interactions.

Comment: @RazaEllahi have you solved your problem?

Comment: yes it solves , but only that expansion panel shows that is selected, i want to display all the panels at the same time

Comment: @RazaEllahi you can use this`@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper; ngAfterViewInit() {this.stepper.selectedIndex = 1;  }` for particular index but according to me at a time all is show it's not possible. for more information check this link https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/api

Comment: I want to set inactive states also expandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, you are creating every time new `mat-vertical-stepper`. You need to add your loop on `mat-step`, not on `mat-vertical-stepper`.

HTML:

```html
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper [linear]="isLinear">
   <mat-step *ngFor="let currentUserInteraction of currentUserInteractions" [stepControl]="currentUserInteraction.key">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>
         {{currentUserInteraction.name}}
      </ng-template>
      <mat-expansion-panel>
         <mat-expansion-panel-header>
         </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
   </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

TypeScript:

```js
currentUserInteractions = [
   {name: 'first', key: 'firstStep'},
   {name: 'second', key: 'secondStep'},
   {name: 'third', key: 'thirdStep'},
   {name: 'fourth', key: 'fourthStep'},
];
```

Also check [this example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aajicd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 2):

You are creating several steppers! You just need to create a step for each of your current user interactions. Try this:

```
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper>
   <mat-step *ngFor="let currentUserInteraction of currentUserInteractions" [stepControl]="currentUserInteraction">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>{{currentUserInteraction.name}}</ng-template>
      <mat-expansion-panel>
         <mat-expansion-panel-header>
         </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
   </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

Comment: I want to set inactive states also expandable.